# Combobox ItemTemplate and foreground

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I have a comboBox that is bound to a list of strings from my viewModel.  What I am trying to do is have the foreground of a comboBox item be set to a different color if a property in my viewModel is true:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Names}">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ...}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy"/>
              </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
      </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I am not sure what to bind the Text of the TextBlock to.  All I want is to display the list of strings.  I always end up with a dropdown that has the items but they are not visible.  I tried removing the style trigger thinking that maybe I was screwing up there, but that didn't help.

Am I taking the right approach?  Will the ComboBox.ItemTemplate correctly look at my viewModel (which is the data context) when searching for IsActive or is that binding incorrect as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataContext` for each `ComboBoxItem` is a string so

- For the `TextBlock`, bind to the `DataContext` like `Text="{Binding}`
- For the `DataTrigger` to be able to find `IsActive`, use `RelativeSource` in the binding

  ```
  <ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Names}">
      <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                  <TextBlock.Style>
                      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                          <Style.Triggers>
                              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}},
                                                             Path=DataContext.IsActive}"
                                           Value="True">
                                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy"/>
                              </DataTrigger>
                          </Style.Triggers>
                      </Style>
                  </TextBlock.Style>
              </TextBlock>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ComboBox>
  ```

Comment: Thanks Meleak.  That helps.  However, I don't see any text in the dropdown.  I don't know what to bind the Text to if I just want to display the list of strings that the comboBox ItemsSource is bound to.  Also, is there a way for my viewModel to return different values of IsActive based on the comboBoxItem that is asking?  I am not sure how my viewModel would know which item is being rendered.

Comment: For your first question, see my updated answer. For your second question, it sounds like you should have a list of a class that holds a string and a boolean.

Comment: Yes, I had a feeling I would need some class to contain the string/bool pair.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Flack: Glad to help :) On a side note, you are very good at accepting answers (which is great) but you have only 4 upvotes. An upvote is always appreciated by someone who is helping you out :)