# Changing color of a TextBlock within a ComboBox through code

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, textblock

I have a few TextBlocks that is stored within my ComboBox. What I would like to do is have each TextBlock have a different font color. I have seen many topics discussing how to do this, but I would like to know if it is possible to do it in code? The reason I ask is because the application connects to a server and gets items from the network which I then set in the TextBlock before pushing the item onto the ComboBox. I set the ForeGround and BackGround based o what the server tells me it should be, but the color always appears as black no matter what. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Do not manipulate UI Elements in code in WPF. No matter the requirement there's always a better no-code XAML-only based way to do it. This isn't winforms

Comment: @HighCore Then in XAML how do you do it?

Comment: @Seb Slugart already answered your question: create an ItemTemplate with bindings

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an ItemTemplate for the combobox and bind the FontColor property to a property in your model.

Check out this Q and A: [Combobox ItemTemplate and foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449034/combobox-itemtemplate-and-foreground)